# Custom map marker icon dimensions for hdpi/mdpi/ldpi

Tags: android, user-interface, maps

I have a custom marker icon with dimensions 40*40 .How must be the dimensions for hdpi/mdpi/ldpi so it will be big enough for the user to press it with ease but not huge on small screens?

[image]

Comment: can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

48dip is considered a good minimum size for a button. That equates to:

```
ldpi: 36px
mdpi: 48px
hdpi: 64px
xhdpi: 96px
xxhdpi: 144px
```

Keep in mind, if you don't want the image to look bigger than it is, you could give it padding, so the touchable area is a bit bigger than the button image.

Google says [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html#create-bitmaps) that you generally don't need to bother with ldpi, because it is exactly half of hdpi, the system can scale the hdpi version down at runtime without blurriness. ldpi devices are a small share of the market anyway (about 8%).

Comment: so my icon would translate in google's ratio at 40x40,50x50,80x80 for l/m/hdpi?

Comment: It depends what size screen you are correlating with 40 pixels. If your mdpi graphic is 40, then ldpi will be 30, hdpi will be 60 and xhdpi will be 80. But what I was suggesting is, if you want it to be a 40dip icon, then put 4dip of invisible pixels all the way around so the touchable area will be 48dip. That will make it an easier target to tap.

Comment: for
xxxhdpi: 192px